# SignalR microservice routing through Ocelot Gateway

Tags: signalr, microservices, .net-6.0, ocelot

I have to develop several microservices which will be routed through ocelot microservice. All the other microservices are working fine when used with ocelot but Unable to connect signalR microservice through ocelot URL. I have followed ocelot documentation as well for ocelot and signalR and web sockets but no help. Is it possible to use ocelot with signalR in 2 different projects? or I should use signalR hubs in same ocelot microservice project?

I am trying to route signalR hubs via ocelot Url and both are individual microservice projects. But get various types of errors.